# run java class from jframe

Tags: java, bluetooth

i am working on program in java, when i clicked Button it will pass string that i get from text field to java class and send it through bluetooth. the problem is when i run my jframe (RegistrasiForm), it seems that my java class(SendtoAndroid.java) didn't run. Can you tell me what's wrong with my program? thanks.

this is my jFrame(RegistrasiForm) code :

```
private void cmd_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("user_id",user_id_text.getText());
    obj.put("password",password_text.getText());

    String kirim = obj.toString();
    SendtoAndroid st=new SendtoAndroid();
    st.setName(kirim);

}catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

}
```

this is my java class (SendtoAndroid.java) code:

public class SendtoAndroid {

```
private String name;
public void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName(){
           return this.name;       
   }

public void startServer() throws IOException, JSONException{
       //Create a UUID for SPP
    UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", true);
    //Create the servicve url
    String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid +";name=Server Bluetooth 2";

    //open server url
    StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open( connectionString );

    //Wait for client connection
    System.out.println("\nServer Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
    StreamConnection connection=streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen();

    RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(connection);
    System.out.println("Remote device address: "+dev.getBluetoothAddress());
    System.out.println("Remote device name: "+dev.getFriendlyName(true));



    //takes string from setName methode 
    String kirim = name;

    //send it via bluetooth
    byte[] msgBuffer = kirim.getBytes();
    OutputStream outStream=connection.openOutputStream();
    outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
    streamConnNotifier.close();
}}
```

Comment: try from this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745330/clicking-a-button-within-a-jframe-passes-an-data-to-a-jpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close, the only part you are missing is that you are not calling the actual method to send your message with bluetooth.

You should call the startServer() method after you set the name, the code should be like this:

```
private void cmd_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("user_id",user_id_text.getText());
        obj.put("password",password_text.getText());

        String kirim = obj.toString();
        SendtoAndroid st=new SendtoAndroid();
        st.setName(kirim);
        st.startServer();

    }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the class instance, set the text, and then fail to call the method that actually sends the message.

So yes, of course the message is never sent, you just throw away the SendToAndroid object without ever telling it to do its job.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand. which part should i repair? could you point it. thanks

Comment: read and try to understand your code, you're missing something. It's too obvious to miss if you understand the code you supposedly wrote yourself, so hand holding isn't needed.